# Proper way to request to separate a 50 dollar banknote

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

How to say correctly if you one from someone who you do not know, to separate a banknote of 50 dollars to 2x5 and 4x10?

What is in my mind is:

> Excuse me, can you exchange this 50dollar banknote to two times 5 and four times 10.

Do you think this is the right way, or there is better way saying that?

Comment: Could you change this fifty into two fives and four tens?

Comment: Even though the other question asks about quarters, I think the answers to both questions are the same. The verbs we typically use are _break_ and _change_ (or sometimes _give change_ or _make change_). Ergo, Michael's suggestion is fine, as is: _Can you make change for a fifty? I need four tens and two fives_.

Comment: In American English, note that we call paper U. S. Dollars  “bills”, not notes, even though they clearly say “Note” right on top of them.   It’s a *twenty dollar bill,* etc.   For the phrase you need, I   agree with J.R.

Comment: ok, the discussion can be closed off now